# Python code explanation need

Tags: python

```
def array_front9(nums):
    end = len(nums)
    if end > 4:
        end = 4

    for i in range(end):
        if nums[i]==9:
            return True
    return False
```

I need to understand the above python code and why two return statement in 'for loop'. This is seriously confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain:

```
def array_front9(nums):   # Define the function "array_front9"
    end = len(nums)       # Get the length of "nums" and put it in the variable "end"
    if end > 4:           # If "end" is greater than 4...
        end = 4           # ...reset "end" to 4

    for i in range(end):  # This iterates through each number contained in the range of "end", placing it in the variable "i"
        if nums[i]==9:    # If the "i" index of "nums" is 9...
            return True   # ...return True because we found what we were looking for
    return False          # If we have got here, return False because we didn't find what we were looking for
```

There are two return-statements  in case the loop falls through (finishes) without returning `True`.

Answer (score 4):

This could be rewritten much simpler (that is, "more pythonic") as this:

```
def array_front9(nums):
   return 9 in nums[:4]
```

The first half of the code is setting the loop limit to the first 4 elements, or less if the array `nums` is shorter.  `nums[:4]` does essentially the same thing by creating a copy that only contains up to the first 4 elements.

The loop is checking to see if the element `9` is found in the loop.  If found, it returns immediately with `True`.  If it's never found, the loop will end and `False` is returned instead.  This is a longhand form of the `in` operator, a built-in part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

The second return *isn't in the for loop*. It provides a return value of `False` if the loop "falls through", when none of `nums[i]` equal 9 in that range.

At least, that's how you've indented it.

Comment: Correct, with one addition: i <= 4

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite this to be more clear using list slicing:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    sublist = nums[:4]

    if 9 in sublist:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```